# Serving files in Node app

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node and I have stumbled into problems when I've tried to deploy my demo app to Digital Ocean. The tutor uses Heroku but I want to use DO to have better control with my apps and to learn more in the end.

On my droplet, I have Ubuntu with Nginx. Also, I use ServerPilot for easy domain/app management. So... I am building simple todo app. Mongo is my database of choice. Everything works locally but when I copy files to my droplet I get 403. I guess server can't render `hbs` files just like that. ServerPilot uses `public` folder as a default so I have this code:

```
app.set('view-engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views','public');
```

Again, on my computer, it works. I can read data from Mongo:

```
{{#each todos}}
    <li>{{this.text}}
      <ul>
        {{this.completed}}
      </ul>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

I have sucesfully installed and connected Mongo on a dropled and it works. I can connect with Robo 3T and manage data.

My question is: what is a correct way to serve files when using node as backend. Should I maybe use gulp for rendering htmls or? I am superconfused.

Comment: Have you tried `express.static`?

Comment: Yes. I have been testing different configs and it seems serverpilot is preventing express in working properly.

Comment: In that case, please give us detailed information on what you're tried and what happened. I'm also not sure why you're using a PHP hosting tool (ServerPilot) for a Node app, this seems to overcomplicate your issues. Have you tried just deploying a Node app to Digital Ocean?